# List tracked files in git-repo

Tags: git

The following shows not only the files in the current repo, but it also shows deleted files:

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```

I tested this by taking an existing repo and deleting a file, commiting the change, and running the above command, and even after the "git commit", the deleted file still shows up in the above list. How do I list "only" the files currently being tracked?

For example, suppose I start with

```
a
b
c/a
```

and I run

```
rm a
git commit -m "test"
```

I need a command to show me:

```
b
c/a
```

Comment: `rm a` && `git commit` will not remove `a` from the commit - in fact, if no other changes have been staged, the commit will fail.

Comment: yeah, I was missing git add (or git commit -a), its working now